# Multiplicity vs Cardinality

Tags: database, uml

When talking about data models and databases, the term **Cardinality** is often used to describe the number of allowed elements in a given set.

UML often refers to the same property as **Multiplicity**.

Is there any difference between these two terms or are they synonymous?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The simplest explanation would be to say:
Multiplicity = Cardinality + Participation

Cardinality: Denotes the maximum number of possible relationship
occurrences in which a certain entity can participate in (in simple terms: at most).

Participation: Denotes if all or only some entity occurrences participate in a relationship (in simple terms: at least).

Ex: [image]

Comment: beware that this representation is for UML. For like Sql relation representations, we place the multiplicity tupple at the beginning of the arrow

Comment: @agenis you are referring to Entity-Relatioship Model, which is different from Object Oriented Model.

Comment: @agenis . . . As far as I understand, the multiplicity is put at the end of an association (with regard to the navigation direction) in other visual diagramming methods as well. [Wikipedia has a nice image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:ERD_Representation.svg) that compares various notations.

Answer (score 31):

Martin Fowler has talked about this subject on his website. Quoting :

> When data modeling methods talk about relationships, they use the term
>   cardinality to indicate how many entities may be linked together. So
>   you might have a relationship between order and customer and say that
>   the cardinality of the relationship is one-to-many. Or you might hear
>   that the cardinality of customers for an order is 0-to-many.
>
> UML avoids the term cardinality preferring to use multiplicity. Often
>   people with a data modeling background are surprised at this since
>   cardinality has been so widely used in data modeling circles.
>
> The reason for the change is that the dictionary definition of
>   cardinality is "the number of elements in a particular set or other
>   grouping" (OED). According to this the data modeling usage is actually
>   wrong. In the excellent UML Reference Manual, Rumbaugh defines
>   multiplicity as "A specification of the range of allowable cardinality
>   values - the size - that a set may assume". The UML uses multiplicity
>   in various places, for a property (association or attribute) and also
>   to show the multiplicity of parts in a composite structure. It's
>   formally defined as a lower and upper bound. An association (the UML
>   equivalent to a relationship in data modeling circles) has a
>   multiplicity for each direction.

[Source](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/MultiplicityNotCardinality.html)

Comment: Fowler might be speaking of old UML versions. UML 2.5 p. 33 explains the term well enough.

Answer (score 26):

Simply put: a *multiplicity* is made up of a lower and an upper *cardinality*. A cardinality is how many elements are in a set. Thus, a multiplicity tells you the minimum and maximum allowed members of the set. They are not synonymous.

Answer (score 7):

Thank you for the question and answers above.

Really got confused with those terms this morning (coffee did not help).

Given the example below:

> 0-1 ---------- 1-*

Multiplicities:

> **First multiplicity**, for the **left entity**: 0-1
>
> **Second multiplicity**, for the **right entity**: 1-*

Cardinalities for the **first multiplicity**:

> **Lower** cardinality: 0
>
> **Upper** cardinality: 1

Cardinalities for the **second multiplicity**:

> **Lower** cardinality: 1
>
> **Upper** cardinality: *

Answer (score 2):

To add the (now) recent UML 2.5 definition on p. 33:

> The cardinality of a collection is the number of values contained in that collection. The multiplicity of a MultiplicityElement specifies valid cardinalities of the collection it represents. The multiplicity is a constraint on the cardinality, which shall not be less than the lower bound and not greater than the upper bound specified for the multiplicity (unless the multiplicity is unlimited, in which case there is no constraint on the upper bound).

Answer (score 1):

The **Multiplicity** is the constraint on the collection of the association objects whereas the **Cardinality** is the count of the objects that are in collection.

The multiplicity is actually the constraint on cardinality.

Answer (score 0):

**A multiplicity of an event = Participation of an element + cardinality of an element.** 
*Participation* means the least number of the occurrence of the entity in a specific relationship whereas *Cardinality* means the maximum (upper bound)and the minimum (lower bound) number of occurrence of the specific entity in a relationship.

FYI: *https://www.uml-diagrams.org/multiplicity.html*