# UML Aggregation Multiplicity

Tags: uml, aggregation, multiplicity

[image: UML Diagram]

What do the diagram's multiplicity values mean?
Do they mean each ShoeStore must have 1 instance of NikeShoes, and that the same instance can be part of many ShoeStore instances? In other words, many ShoeStores might have the same pair of shoes (an instance, not the type) to sell? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that is what it means. I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate question though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiplicity vs Cardinality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17877582/multiplicity-vs-cardinality)

Comment: @GeertBellekens The OP is not asking about cardinality...

Comment: @qwerty_so I know, but the answers there answer this question as well.

Answer (score 0):

The `1` multiplicity is a defined shortcut for `1..1`, meaning that every instance of `ShoeStore` must have at minimum and and maximum 1 instance of `NikeShoe`.

The reverse `*` multiplicity is a defined shortcut for `0..*` which means that an instance of `NikeShoe` can be part minimum 0 and maximum an infinity of  instances of `ShoeShop`.

Answer (score 0):

The diagram shows a shared aggregation relation. As per UML 2.5 this has no defined semantics. P. 110:

> shared | Indicates that the Property has shared aggregation semantics. Precise semantics of shared aggregation varies by application area and modeler.

So what is left is an association (except there is some hidden document explaining the exact semantics of the diamond). And that means you can have 1 `NikeShoes` in 0..n `ShoeStore`.  What ever that might mean.

Regarding multiplicities: pp. 34 of UML 2.5 says

> A multiplicity with zero as the lower bound and an unspecified upper bound may use the alternative notation containing a single star “`*`” instead of “`0..*`” multiplicity.